Spatial effects competing for variance with error term?
I am simulating a dataset from a spatial model. Each data point is distributed as follows:
$$
y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu + \phi_i, \sigma^2)
$$
Here $\mu$ is a fixed value, estimated as an intercept. The $\phi_i$ term is a spatial random effect, which is distributed as follows:
$$
\phi_i | \boldsymbol{\phi}_{-i}, \tau_{\phi} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\sum_{i \in \delta_i} \frac{\phi_i}{|\delta_i|}, \frac{1}{\tau_{\phi} |\delta_i|}\right)
$$
where $\tau_\phi$ is the precision and $|\delta_i|$ is the number of elements in the $i^{th}$ neighborhood.
What happens when I estimate this with either INLA or a Gibbs-sampler, is that it tends poorly estimate $\sigma^2$ and $\tau_{\phi}$. Especially when $\sigma^2$ is large, the two estimates are poor. It tends to then overestimate $\sigma^2$ and set $\tau_\phi$ to zero. I tried checking the priors, but those are both vague, so the two terms are more or less unconstrained.
What is causing this? Do the variance terms compete with each other? What could solve this?
